# NodeJs unable to save all rows from csv into Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

I have a node.js server, what i'm trying to do is read name of a csv file via a post request which will then prompt the server to read a UTF-8 encoded csv file to be read which is placed in the public/files folder inside the backend folder and row by row each record be entered into mongodb.

But the problem that is arising is that, only 50 entries are being entered into mongodb.

The response, "ALL rounders added successfully" is sent to postman but still the console keeps showing the "Added allrounder" console.log .

I would like to know what i'm doing wrong as i've waited for a while but Robo 3T is showing only 50 entries in the Allrounder collection.

Node.js server part :

```
router.post(("/allrounders/addFile"),(req, res) =>
{
    const file_name = req.body.name;
    const file_path = path.join(__dirname,"..","public","files",`${file_name}.csv`);


    let stream = fs.createReadStream(file_path);

    stream.pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
                
            var name = (row['﻿Name']);
            var country = (row["Country"]);
            var starting_year = (row['Starting Year']);
            var ending_year = (row['Ending Year']);
            var matches = (row["Matches"]);
            var Batting_Runs = (row['Batting Runs']);
            var highest_score = (row['Highest Score']);
            var Batting_Average = (row['Batting Average']);
            var Hundreds = (row["Hundreds"]);
            var Wickets = (row["Wickets"]);
            var best_bowling_figures_wickets = (row['Best Bowling Figures Wickets']);
            var best_bowling_figures_runs = (row['Best Bowling Figures Runs']);
            var Bowling_Average = (row['Bowling Average']);
            var five_Wickets = (row['5 Wickets']);
            // Difference between batting and bowling average. , if +ve then a better batsman, else bowler
            var Average_Difference = (row['Average Difference']);
            let wickets2;
            // WIckets
            if(Wickets.includes("-"))
            {
                wickets2 = 0
            }
            else
            {
                wickets2 = Wickets
            }

            // Best FIgures 
            let best_bowling_figures_wickets2;
            let best_bowling_figures_runs2;
            if(best_bowling_figures_wickets.includes("-"))
            {
                best_bowling_figures_wickets2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                best_bowling_figures_wickets2 = best_bowling_figures_wickets
            }

            if(best_bowling_figures_runs.includes("-"))
            {
                best_bowling_figures_runs2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                best_bowling_figures_runs2 = best_bowling_figures_runs;
            }

            // Bowling average

            let Bowling_Average2;

            if(Bowling_Average.includes("-"))
            {
                Bowling_Average2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Bowling_Average2 = Bowling_Average;
            }

            // Five wickets
            let five_Wickets2;
            if(five_Wickets.includes("-"))
            {
                five_Wickets2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                five_Wickets2 = five_Wickets;
            }

            // Average difference

            let Average_Difference2;
            if(Average_Difference.includes("-"))
            {
                Average_Difference2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Average_Difference2 = Average_Difference;
            }


            // highest score
            var out_status_for_highestscore;
            if(highest_score.includes("*"))
            {
                out_status_for_highestscore = false;
            }
            else
            {
                out_status_for_highestscore = true;
            }
            let temp_var_highestscore = highest_score.split("*");
            var highest_score_runs = temp_var_highestscore[0];

            // Make new obj to be saved in DB
            const newAllrounder = new Allrounder({
                name: name,
                country: country,
                wicket_keeper : false,
                span: {starting_year : starting_year,
                    ending_year:ending_year },
                matches: matches,
                batting_runs:Batting_Runs,
                highest_score:{
                    highest_runs : highest_score_runs,
                    out: out_status_for_highestscore
                },
                batting_average: Batting_Average,
                hundreds:Hundreds,
                wickets:wickets2,
                best_figures:{
                    runs : best_bowling_figures_runs2,
                    wickets:best_bowling_figures_wickets2
                },
                bowling_average:Bowling_Average2,
                five_wickets:five_Wickets2,
                average_difference:Average_Difference2

            });
            newAllrounder.save()
            .then(results =>console.log("Allround added"))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error saving All rounders  " + err));
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
        res.json("ALL rounders added successfully");
        
    }
    )
    .on('error', () => {
        res.status(400).json("Error Processing the CSV file correctly");
    });

});
```

My Allrounder Model :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const allrounderSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            trim: true
        },
        
        country:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            trim: true
        },
        wicket_keeper : 
        {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        span:
        {
            starting_year : 
            {
                type:Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            },
            ending_year:
            {
                type:Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            }

        }
        ,
        matches:
        {
            type:Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        batting_runs:
        {
            type:Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        highest_score:
        {
            highest_runs : 
            {
                type:Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            },
            out:
            {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            }
        }
        ,
        batting_average:
        {
                type:Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
        },
        hundreds:
        {
                type:Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
        },
        wickets:
        {
            type:Number,
            required:true,
            trim: true
        }
        ,
        best_figures:
        {
            runs : 
            {
                type:Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            },
            wickets:
            {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            }
        },
        bowling_average:
        {
                type:Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
        },
        five_wickets:
        {
                type:Number,
                required: true,
                trim: true
        },
        average_difference:
        { 
            type:Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true

        }
    });

    const Allrounder = mongoose.model("Allrounder",allrounderSchema);
    
    module.exports = Allrounder;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server side you have **Readable** not being [paused](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) and by saving your MongoDB object you get a promise. What you should do is store your readable in a variable instead of directly call the method **.on()**. If you store your readable you are able to **pause** and [resume](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) your csv data so you can avoid to skip some entries. Use the following code:

```
router.post(("/allrounders/addFile"),(req, res) =>
{
   const file_name = req.body.name;
   const file_path = path.join(__dirname,"..","public","files",`${file_name}.csv`);


   let readable = fs.createReadStream(file_path).pipe(csv());

   readable.on('data', (row) => {
            
        var name = (row['﻿Name']);
        
        // Your code ...

        // Make new obj to be saved in DB
        // Your object Defined

        readable.pause() // HERE pause your readable

        newAllrounder.save()
        .then(results => {
           console.log("Allround added");
           readable.resume(); // When you promise is resolved you resume your readable
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error saving All rounders  " + err));
   });

   readable.on('end', () => {
      console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
      res.json("ALL rounders added successfully");
   });

   readable.on('error', () => {
      res.status(400).json("Error Processing the CSV file correctly");
   });

});
```

Comment: Jose Vasquez, thanks this has worked. But, i found something stupid that was actually causing this problem, the thing was that my previous code itself was working too but the dataset i had downloaded was incorrect as it only had 50 rows which were repeated multiple times till it reached 2500 rows. 
i fixed that and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`newAllrounder.save()` is asynchronous.  The loop does not wait for it to complete before beginning the next iteration.  When the loop finishes, it returns even though there are, by that point, many save operations incomplete.  As each one completes, the `then` is executed, so these messages continue even after the response has been sent.